# How do I save a list to a CSV in Python

Tags: python, csv, save

I have been trying to save a list to a CSV for my adventure game I am working on but I can't seem to find anything that works online, this is the code I have,

```
import csv
testarray = ["Hello", "My", "Name", "is", "John"]
wtr = csv.writer(open ('test.csv', 'w'), delimiter=';', lineterminator='\n')
for x in testarray : wtr.writerow ([x])
for label in testarray:
  testarray.write([label])
print("Done!")
```

Sorry if this was set out poorly I'm kind of new to this. Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: What is the question? There is no question here.

Comment: @zvone - The question is simply how to write a list to a `csv` file.

Comment: @SvetlanaofVodianova If that was really the question, then the answer would be simply _"read the [`csv` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)"_. There is an example there doing exctly that. The OP is having some trouble with it, but has not taken time to find out what it is that they want to ask.

Comment: You should clearly state your output first, so we can provide an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before I  post an answer let me take the time to explain what you're doing wrong so you don't repeat the same bad habits.

This line could be written better:

```
wtr = csv.writer(open ('test.csv', 'w'), delimiter=';', lineterminator='\n')
```

In `Python` it can be written as:

```
with open('items.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
```

In your code sample, you never used `with`. It's a good time to read about [why you should use it](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with).

Under that you can specify how and what to write, like this:

```
item_writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
```

This for loop could be written better:

```
for label in testarray:
  testarray.write([label])
```

You don't need to surround the `label` variable with `[]` brackets because it's not a `list`. You are referencing items from the `list`.

It can be written like this:

```
for item in testarray:
    item_writer.writerow(item)
```

This may not be what you want, because it will write every item in the `list` on it's own line.

Putting everything together, we get:

```
import csv


def main():

    testarray = ["Hello", "My", "Name", "is", "John"]

    with open('test.csv', mode='w') as employee_file:
        employee_writer = csv.writer(employee_file, delimiter=',',  quotechar='"', 
                                     quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        employee_writer.writerow(testarray)

    print("done")

 # Will output:
 # Hello,My,Name,is,John

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to make sure that every letter is not separated by a space? BTW this code is not my own, I copied it off of another question to see if it would work and it did not, clearly. 

Comment: You say "doesnt make sense" twice, but that's unfair. To focus on the first example; it _does_ pass a file object to `csv.writer()`. Saying it doesn't make sense... doesnt make sense. It's not to your liking but that is different

Comment: @roganjosh - When I say it doesn't make sense, I mean two things, 1. no `with` statement, and 2. It's not written in a pythonic way, no indents by 4 spaces and everything is written in one line. The code might work, but it could be written better.

Comment: I won't disagree with that. But I'd caution against "doesn't make sense". It _does_ make sense, it's just not best practice. I'm not jumping on welcoming wagon but it comes across as the whole approach is wrong

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the help everyone, I have managed to get my program to work now 

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import csv

testarray = ["Hello", "My", "Name", "is", "John"]

with open('test.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer= csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ',quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    writer.writerow(testarray)
```

this is from the page:  [CSV File Reading and Writing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)

Worth a read through so you understand why it works.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply, is there a way to make every element g o onto a different line?

Comment: Yes, simply loop through the testarray object and repeat the writer.writerow() with each element as write row adds another row with the thing you pass to it

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand, is it possible for you to give me a code example? No worries if not.

Comment: no worries. the answer SvetlanaofVodianova gave is the full answer and should accepted

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help, will wait for a reply from them.

Comment: Its already there mate, just above this answer:

'with open('eggs.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
        item_writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        for item in testarray:
            item_writer.writerow(item)'


That bit

Comment: @Lordimass - If you want every element on it's own line, then their is no need for `csv`. You just want to write a list of elements to a file.

Answer (score 1):

I would use Pandas Dataframe to build the dataframe and save it to CSV. If you want  elements from a list in separate line do this

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.Dataframe(testarray)
```

If you want all elements of a list in a single row do this

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([testarray])
```

## save it as

```
df1.to_csv("my_test.csv", index = False)
```

you can add column names in dataframe if you want.

If you have list of list as follows:

```
list_of_list = [['A', 15], ['B', 30], 
       ['C', 45], ['D', 22]]
```

You can simply perform same as follows, with labelled columns

```
df_again = pd.DataFrame(list_of_list, columns =['letter', 'number']) 
df_again.to_csv("new_one.csv", index = False)
```

Comment: all that happens when I run this code is that it say that pandas is not a valid module

Comment: You need to install pandas, you can find here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/install.html